# I want to push this file to my cell phone

Tags: adb

I do adb shell

Then I do ls

```
~ $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Feb 14 08:54 cache
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            13 Jan  1  1970 charger -> /sbin/healthd
drwxrwxr-x    7 system   system        4096 Jan  2  2000 config
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2925 Jan  1  1970 config_init.sh
drwxrwx--x    4 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 data
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 datadata
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4350 Jan  1  1970 default.prop
drwxr-xr-x   12 root     root          3140 Feb 14 11:15 dev
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1320 Jan  1  1970 droidboot.init.mofd_v1.rc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 emmc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 external_sd
drwxrwx---    7 system   system        4096 Nov 15 10:10 factory
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         16565 Jan  1  1970 file_contexts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1604 Jan  1  1970 fstab
-rw-r-----    1 root     root           595 Jan  1  1970 fstab.charger.mofd_v1
-rw-r-----    1 root     root           806 Jan  1  1970 fstab.mofd_v1
-rw-r-----    1 root     root           595 Jan  1  1970 fstab.ramconsole.mofd_v1
-rw-r-----    1 root     root           151 Jan  1  1970 fstab.zram
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root        653412 Jan  1  1970 init
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          1938 Jan  1  1970 init.class_main.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root           109 Jan  1  1970 init.firmware.rc
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          5253 Jan  1  1970 init.rc
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root           436 Jan  1  1970 init.watchdog.rc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1081 Jan  1  1970 intel_prop.cfg
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 lib
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 Feb 14 09:47 logs -> /data/logs
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 mnt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3220 Feb 14 09:56 original.fstab
dr-xr-xr-x  125 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:47 proc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3070 Jan  1  1970 property_contexts
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:56 res
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           240 Jan  1  1970 rfkill_bt.sh
drwx------    2 root     root             0 Jun 26  2015 root
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     shell            0 Feb 14 09:56 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 sd-ext
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Feb 14 09:57 sdcard -> /data/media
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           534 Jan  1  1970 seapp_contexts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            73 Jan  1  1970 selinux_version
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        141154 Jan  1  1970 sepolicy
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         10548 Jan  1  1970 service_contexts
dr-xr-xr-x   14 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:47 sys
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 system
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb 14 09:57 tmp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3388 Jan  1  1970 ueventd.mofd_v1.rc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4487 Jan  1  1970 ueventd.rc
```

Now there is a zip file that contains my cyanogenmod. However, I couldn't find in which directory it is.

It is on the external sd card.

So how can I push some files to the root directory of my external sd card?

I did

```
cd /
ls -R *.zip
```

I got nothing even though I know that some zip files definitely exist

I did cd /external_sd

But the directory is empty

Comment: If it is for installation, you can use an app like WebPCSuite?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push your files inside sdcard. You need to push it inside /mnt/sdcard/. That is where your sdcard is mounted inside adb shell

Comment: I think this has to do with device or Android version. In my Android 4.2.1, external SD card is mounted at /storage/sdcard0 and /mnt/sdcard is a symlink to it. // Your second part has an issue. The card is mounted by Android at boot or when it is plugged after boot. `adb shell` has no role in it.

Comment: Yes by default sdcard is mounted on /storage/sdacrd0 but his screenshot has no listing of storage folder. So i suggested this one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the name of the directory is /external_sd/

```
c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb push BlissPop-v4.0.3-Z00A-NIGHTLY-20160207-0726.zip /external_sd/
4930 KB/s (401167841 bytes in 79.457s)

c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb push cm-12.1-20160208-UNOFFICIAL-Z00A.zip /external_sd/
5369 KB/s (358202764 bytes in 65.145s)

c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb push Slim-z00a-5.1.1.beta.0.5-OFFICIAL-8-16-15.zip /external_sd
5001 KB/s (312582947 bytes in 61.032s)
```

However, if I go to `adb shell`

And I do

cd /external_sd
ls

I see nothing.

However, CWM can see the zip files on my /external_sd